# Lost activities in Aggregated Feed

Tags: stream-framework

first of all a little of what I am trying to achieve. I have built a django wrapper on top of stream-framework library. There are 2 feed-classes - `FlatFeed(RedisFeed)` and `AggregatedFeed(RedisAggregatedFeed)`. Obviously, these are using Redis to store the feed data. I have also implemented my own aggregator class.

**Error**: The generated aggregated feed doesn't contain all activities while the flat feed has all the activities. The use-case is - there are 3 users A, B and C. B and C performs some activities, then user A follows B and C. User B and C keep on doing more activities. Flat feed of A contains all the activities of B and C, but aggregated feed of A has some lost activities.

For example,

```
B likes products 1, 2, 3, 4
C likes products 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
A follows B
A follows C
```

flat_feed(A) has all activities, but `aggregated_feed(A)` only has likes for 1, 5 and 8. I repeated this use-case several times and each time only these 3 activities are coming.

I have tested my aggregator class implementation on django shell. The output of aggregate and merge function contains all the activities.

Please help !!

Please note that flat feed has correct entries, the missing entries are only in aggregated feeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the `AggregatedActivity` class of the framework, you will notice that the `serialization_id` aka the unique identifier of the activity is calculated based on the number of seconds from epoch. This means that the activities that are performed within one second will be overwritten.

You can solve this by redefining the `serialization_id`.
`serialization_id` = number of **milliseconds** from epoch.
This should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. I rewrote the `serialization_id` method of `AggregatedActivity` as -

```
def serialization_id(self):
    milliseconds = str(int(datetime_to_epoch(self.updated_at)* 1000))
    return milliseconds
```